# HR Template value are not setting in HR Case when a new case created manually

Tags: servicenow, portal, servicenow-hrsd

Hello team I have an `HR Service` and added `priority` for that in `HR Template`.

On the `priority` configure dictionary default value is set to "LOW" (OOB Out of the box)

> Technically it should override the `default value` and update based on
> `HR Service->HR Template`, but it's not working as expected.

I tried the following:
Verified all the:

1. Business rules
2. Client Scripts
3. Case Creation Configuration

None of them are causing this issue

1.HR Service:
[image]

2.Manual Case Creation UI Page (Servicenow OOB):
[image]

3.Case after creation:

> Priority is set to `LOW(4)` instead of `Moderate(3)`

[image]

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if there is any script that is being used to manipulate the priority field, in general case there is a data look up defined for the priority field you can check that also if that is causing this behaviour.
I tried it with an HR template and it worked fine for me :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRxos.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRSpL.png)

Comment: I tried to find all the possible ways but no luck.

Finally Using Dictionary override I resolved the issues.
For HR Cases i removed the default value of '4'